Performance Issues with UI Automation Tree Search in a Large UI Structure (Table) Using C++
Problem Description:
I am working with the UI Automation framework in C++ to find a particular element in a large UI structure, such as a table (similar to Excel). The target element may be deeply nested, for example, in the 90th row and 100th column, which is causing significant performance issues in my current implementation.
Original Implementation:
The original code uses Depth-First Search (DFS) to iterate through the UI elements. It builds a cache for each element as it traverses the tree, which I suspect is causing the performance issues. Here's a simplified version of the function:
std::shared_ptr<IUIElement> UIAutomationSession::FindElement(
    HWND topWnd, PCWCHAR name, LONG classTypeId, LONG x, LONG y, LONG w, LONG h)
{
    LOG_TRACE(L"BEGIN");

    auto element = root->ElementFromHandleBuildCacheNoThrow(topWnd, cache.get()).value; // Invokes IUIAutomation::ElementFromHandleBuildCache
    if (element)
    {
        RECT wndRect;
        windowApi->GetWindowRect(topWnd, &wndRect);

        return FindElement(element.get(), wndRect, x, y, w, h);
    }
    else
    {
        element = root->ElementFromHandleNoThrow(topWnd).value; // Invokes IUIAutomation::ElementFromHandle
        if (element)
        {
            cache->PutTreeScope(TreeScope_Element);
            AddCacheableProperties(CachingPropertySets::TREEWALKER_SEARCH_PROP_SET);

            auto rawWalker = root->GetRawViewWalkerNoThrow().value; // Invokes IUIAutomation::get_RawViewWalker
            if (rawWalker)
            {
                std::function<std::shared_ptr<IUIElement>(IUIElement*)> F
                    = [&](IUIElement* processingElement) -> std::shared_ptr<IUIElement>
                {
                    auto currentElement = rawWalker->GetFirstChildElementBuildCacheNoThrow(processingElement, cache.get()).value; // Invokes IUIAutomationTreeWalker::GetFirstChildElementBuildCache
                    if (currentElement)
                    {
                        while (currentElement != nullptr)
                        {
                            const auto manipulator = factory->MakeManipulator(topWnd, currentElement);
                            const auto elementName = manipulator->GetName();
                            const auto elementTypeId = currentElement->GetCachedControlTypeNoThrow().value; // Invokes IUIAutomationElement::GetCachedPropertyValue

                            if (elementName == name && elementTypeId == classTypeId)
                            {
                                return currentElement;
                            }

                            auto targetElement = F(currentElement.get());

                            if (targetElement != nullptr)
                            {
                                return targetElement;
                            }

                            currentElement = rawWalker
                                ->GetNextSiblingElementBuildCacheNoThrow(currentElement.get(), cache.get()).value; // Invokes IUIAutomationTreeWalker::GetNextSiblingElementBuildCache
                        }
                    }

                    return nullptr;
                };

                return F(element.get());
            }
        }
    }

    return {};
}

Problem with Original Implementation:

Performance Bottleneck: The function seems to be building the cache for each element repeatedly as it traverses the tree. This leads to significant delays when the element is deeply nested, especially in large UI tables.

My Attempt at Optimization:
I rewrote the function to build the cache for the entire subtree upfront (using TreeScope_Subtree) and changed the traversal algorithm from DFS to Breadth-First Search (BFS). However, the revised version does not find elements that require scrolling (both vertically and horizontally) to be visible. It only finds elements already visible in the current UI viewport.
Here's the optimized version I came up with:
std::shared_ptr<IUIElement> UIAutomationSession::FindElement(
    HWND topWnd, PCWCHAR name, LONG classTypeId, LONG x, LONG y, LONG w, LONG h)
{
    LOG_TRACE(L"BEGIN");

    // Build cache for the entire tree
    cache->PutTreeScope(TreeScope_Subtree);
    AddCacheableProperties(CachingPropertySets::TREEWALKER_SEARCH_PROP_SET);

    LOG_DEBUG(L"Name of the element: {}", name);
    LOG_DEBUG(L"Class ID: {}, x: {}, y: {}, w: {}, z: {}", classTypeId, x, y, w, h);

    auto element = root->ElementFromHandleBuildCacheNoThrow(topWnd, cache.get()).value;
    if (!element)
    {
        LOG_DEBUG(L"!element is true");
        element = root->ElementFromHandleNoThrow(topWnd).value;
    }

    if (!element)
    {
        LOG_DEBUG(L"!element is true, returning nullptr");
        return nullptr;
    }

    auto rawWalker = root->GetRawViewWalkerNoThrow().value;

    if (!rawWalker)
    {
        LOG_DEBUG(L"!rawWalker is true, returning nullptr");
        return nullptr;
    }
    
    LOG_DEBUG(L"IUITreeWalker count is: {}", rawWalker.use_count());

    std::function<std::shared_ptr<IUIElement>(IUIElement*)> FindTargetElement = [&](IUIElement* startElement) -> std::shared_ptr<IUIElement>
    {
        std::queue<std::shared_ptr<IUIElement>> queue;
        queue.push(std::shared_ptr<IUIElement>(startElement, [](IUIElement*) {}));

        while (!queue.empty())
        {
            auto current = queue.front();
            queue.pop();
            auto controlType = current->GetCachedControlTypeNoThrow().value;
            LOG_DEBUG(L"Cached Control Type: {}", controlType);

            if (controlType == classTypeId)
            {
                const auto currentName = current->GetCachedNameNoThrow().value;
                const auto currentClassId = current->GetCachedControlTypeNoThrow().value;
                LOG_DEBUG(L"The current class ID of the element: {}", currentClassId);
                LOG_DEBUG(L"Get cached name of the control: {}", currentName);

                if (currentName == name && classTypeId == currentClassId)
                {
                    LOG_DEBUG(L"Retrieved name and class type ID matched with the passed one!");
                    return current;
                }
            }
            LOG_DEBUG(L"Getting children of current node");
            auto children = current->GetCachedChildrenNoThrow().value;
            if (children)
            {
                LOG_DEBUG(L"There are children. Number is: {}", children.use_count());
                for (int i = 0; i < children->GetLengthNoThrow().value; ++i)
                {
                    queue.push(children->GetElementNoThrow(i).value);
                }
            }
        }
        LOG_DEBUG(L"Did not find the element we were looking for :(");
        return nullptr;
    };

    LOG_DEBUG(L"Call lambda recursively");
    auto targetElement = FindTargetElement(element.get());
    if (targetElement)
    {
        LOG_DEBUG(L"Got the element? Yeah!!");
        return targetElement;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

Problem with Optimized Implementation:

Does not find elements that require scrolling: It seems like the optimization works only for elements that are already visible in the UI. It cannot find elements that are outside the current viewport and require scrolling (both vertical and horizontal) to be accessed, it find horizontal scroller but not vertical.


Question:

What are the performance bottlenecks in the original implementation? Why is it taking so long for deeply nested elements (e.g., in a table)?
Why does my optimized version fail to find elements that require scrolling? How can I improve this to handle elements that are not immediately visible in the current viewport?

Any guidance, suggestions, or improvements would be greatly appreciated!

Additional Context:

UI Automation Framework: Microsoft UI Automation in C++.
Target UI: A table/grid-like structure (similar to Excel) with many rows and columns.
Current Tools: Using IUIAutomationElement, IUIAutomationTreeWalker, and caching strategies for performance optimization.


Your UI component should implement the grid and table pattern like Excel does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-controlpatternsoverview otherwise you're basically doomed, this is typically what patterns are for.

@SimonMourier Thanks for direction. If possible, can I ask you to review the functions?

What functions?

@SimonMourier The first function in my question. If possible, I have no one to review my code at my workplace, so I was wondering if you could take a look if possible.

When using COM, I wouldn't use stl smart pointers but instead C++/WinRT ones. Also you don't need to access "Cached" values, my experience shows it doesn't help in any way. The main problem is you shouldn't browse all items and doing that recursively is worse (you can hang your program). What you want to do is 1) use discriminent Find methods with conditions (on control name, control type, automation id, etc.), and use UIA patterns when available.
